# Conversion of minimax with alpha beta pruning to negamax

Tags: c++, algorithm, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I've written a [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) algorithm with [alpha beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning) for the game Checkers, and now I'm trying to rewrite it using the [negamax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax) approach. I'm expecting the two to be equivalent, since negamax is just a technique to write the minimax. But for some reason my two algorithms behave differently. When I run them both on the same input, the negamax version seems to evaluate more states, so I think something must be wrong with the alpha beta pruning.

The code below shows both algorithms (`minimax` and `negamax` functions), and at the bottom the `play` function from which I call them. The `evaluate` function is the basic heuristic which I use to evaluate states in both algorithms.

Any help with spotting the error would be much appriciated.

```
#include "player.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace checkers
{

int evaluatedStates = 0;

int evaluate(const GameState &state)
{
    // FIXME: Improve heuristics.
    int redScore = 0;
    int whiteScore = 0;
    int piece = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 32; ++i)
    {
        piece = state.at(i);
        if (piece & CELL_RED) {
            ++redScore;
            if (piece & CELL_KING)
                redScore += 2;   // King bonus.
        } else if (piece & CELL_WHITE) {
            ++whiteScore;
            if (piece & CELL_KING)
                whiteScore += 2; // King bonus.
        }
    }
    return state.getNextPlayer() == CELL_RED ? whiteScore - redScore : redScore - whiteScore;
}

int minimax(const GameState &state, int depth, int a, int b, bool max)
{
    if (depth == 0 || state.isEOG()) {
        ++evaluatedStates;
        return evaluate(state);
    }
    std::vector<GameState> possibleMoves;
    state.findPossibleMoves(possibleMoves);
    if (max) {
        for (const GameState &move : possibleMoves) {
            a = std::max(a, minimax(move, depth - 1, a, b, false));
            if (b <= a)
                return b; // β cutoff.
        }
        return a;
    } else {
        for (const GameState &move : possibleMoves) {
            b = std::min(b, minimax(move, depth - 1, a, b, true));
            if (b <= a)
                return a; // α cutoff.
        }
        return b;
    }
}

int negamax(const GameState &state, int depth, int a, int b)
{
    if (depth == 0 || state.isEOG()) {
        ++evaluatedStates;
        return evaluate(state);
    }
    std::vector<GameState> possibleMoves;
    state.findPossibleMoves(possibleMoves);
    for (const GameState &move : possibleMoves) {
        a = std::max(a, -negamax(move, depth - 1, -b, -a));
        if (b <= a)
            return b; // β cutoff.
    }
    return a;
}

GameState Player::play(const GameState &pState, const Deadline &pDue)
{
    GameState bestMove(pState, Move());

    std::vector<GameState> possibleMoves;
    pState.findPossibleMoves(possibleMoves);

    int a = -std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int b = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for (const GameState &move : possibleMoves) {
        int v = negamax(move, 10, a, b);
        //int v = minimax(move, 10, a, b, false);
        if (v > a) {
            a = v;
            bestMove = move;
        }
    }
    std::cerr << "Evaluated states: " << evaluatedStates << std::endl;
    return bestMove;
}

/*namespace checkers*/ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `minimax()` and `negamax()` functions are correct. I assume that `state.getNextPlayer()` returns the player who has to move next. That means that your `evaluate()` and `negamax()` functions return a score from the perspective of that player.

However, the `minimax()` returns a score from the perspective of `max`. So if you try uncommenting `minimax()` in your `play()` function, that would lead to a bug

```
//int v = negamax(move, 10, a, b);
int v = minimax(move, 10, a, b, false); // assumes perspective of min player
                                ^^^^^

if (v > a) {                            // assumes perspective of max player
    a = v;
    bestMove = move;
}
```

Replacing the call to `minimax()` with a `true` parameter should solve it:

```
int v = minimax(move, 10, a, b, true); // assumes perspective of max player
```

Comment: Spot on. That was it. Thanks a lot, and your assumption about getNextPlayer() was correct.

Comment: glad to have been of help for a fellow checkers programmer :-)

Comment: btw, I think it would be slightly better to name it `playerToMoveNext()`