# I want to modify the unbeatable tic tac to work for 5 by 5 block by introducing the depth to limit the search levels. Any suggestions?

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

Here's the code snippet for the minimax algorithm. For a 5 by 5 matrix it seems to take a lot of time. I want to introduce a variable that keeps track of the depth of the recursion and limits it. Here's the link to the entire code : http://ideone.com/e.js/pyFHRu

```
int MiniMax(char _board[25], player _player) {
    int best_val = -INFINITY, index = 0;
    std::list<int> move_list;
    char best_moves[25] = {0};
    generate_moves(_board, move_list);
    while(!move_list.empty()) {
        _board[move_list.front()] = _player.symbol;
        cSymbol = _player.symbol;
        int val = MinMove(_board, _player);
        if(val > best_val) {
            best_val = val;
            index = 0;
            best_moves[index] = move_list.front() + 1;
        } else if(val == best_val) {
            best_moves[++index] = move_list.front() + 1;
        }
        _board[move_list.front()] = 0;
        move_list.pop_front();
    }
    if(index > 0) {
        index = rand() % index;
    }
    return best_moves[index];
}

// finds best move for 'min player'
int MinMove(char _board[25], player _player) {
    int pos_value = evaluate_position(_board, _player);
    if(pos_value != -1) {
        return pos_value;
    }
    int best_val = +INFINITY;
    std::list<int> move_list;
    generate_moves(_board, move_list);
    while(!move_list.empty()) {
        _player.symbol == 'X' ? cSymbol = 'O' : cSymbol = 'X';
        _board[move_list.front()] = cSymbol;
        int val = MaxMove(_board, _player);
        if(val < best_val) {
            best_val = val;
        }
        _board[move_list.front()] = 0;
        move_list.pop_front();
    }
    return best_val;
}

// finds best move for 'max player'
int MaxMove(char _board[25], player _player) {
    int pos_value = evaluate_position(_board, _player);
    if(pos_value != -1) {
        return pos_value;
    }
    int best_val = -INFINITY;
    std::list<int> move_list;
    generate_moves(_board, move_list);
    while(!move_list.empty()) {
        _player.symbol == 'X' ? cSymbol = 'X' : cSymbol = 'O';
        _board[move_list.front()] = cSymbol;
        int val = MinMove(_board, _player);
        if(val > best_val) {
            best_val = val;
        }
        _board[move_list.front()] = 0;
        move_list.pop_front();
    }
    return best_val;
}
```

Comment: _'I want to introduce a variable that keeps track of the depth'_ You'll need a reference parameter passed through to do this.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Like where exactly should I introduce it?

Comment: _'where exactly should I introduce it'_ As a parameter of the recursvely called function. Decrement ít with every recursve call, stop recursion if it's zero.

Comment: Which variable(among the ones shown in the code snippet)should I return when the parameter,say depth becomes 0?

Comment: It is inexplicable to me why you are juggling with raw arrays when you already seem to be aware of standard containers like `std::list`. Why don't you replace your raw char arrays with `std::vector<char>`? Then you can easily let the user choose the board size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already working with smaller depth, then you have to calculate heuristics. Heuristics is a value between -1 and 1 showing the position evaluation. If you have a depth of 10 (you calculate 10 plies), then you need to calculate heuristics when you reach the final position of your evaluation (depth is 0 or somebody has won).

Thus, we can reach to a MiniMax algorithm with limited maximal depth, where you calculate the evaluation of the resulting position with a heuristic function if the game is not won. If you want to eliminate the seemingly useless branches of your evaluation tree using heuristics to further optimize evaluation time, then you can use Alpha-Beta prunning, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816088/conversion-of-minimax-with-alpha-beta-pruning-to-negamax) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ewh-rF7KSEg).